# Generate random sparse matrix filled with only values 0 or 1

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to generate a random csr_matrix using SciPy but I need it to only be filled with values 0 or 1.

So far I'm trying to use:

`rand(1000, 10, density=0.2, format='csr', random_state=np.random.randint(0, 2))`

and I get the correct structure and density I want, but the values filling it are floats between 0 and 1.

Is there a way to generate this structure with just floats of 0 or 1?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could simply replace the non-zero values in your random matrix with ones:

```
from scipy.sparse import rand

x = rand(1000, 10, density=0.2, format='csr')
x.data[:] = 1

print(np.unique(x.todense().flat))
# [ 0.  1.]
```

I don't think that the `random_state=` kwarg does what you think it does - it simply allows you to either specify the seed for the random number generator, or to explicitly pass an `np.random.RandomState` instance to serve as the RNG.

Comment: Is there some reason why I can't do `x[0].data[:] = 0.5` to change the values in the just the first row of the matrix only?

If I do `temp = x[0]` and then `temp.data[:] = 0.5`, this works, but I need to update the row in the actual matrix.

Comment: The reason is that indexing into a CSR matrix always generates a copy. You could find out how many non-zero elements there are in the first row, then set the corresponding number of data values to 0.5, e.g. `x.data[:x[0].nnz] = 0.5`.

Comment: ...or for an arbitrary row number you could use the [`.indptr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) attribute to find the corresponding indices into `.data`, e.g. `x.data[x.indptr[i]:x.indptr[i+1]] = 0.5` to set the value of the `i`th row

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
import scipy.sparse as ss
data = ss.random(1000, 10, density=.2, format='csr',
                 data_rvs=np.ones,   # fill with ones
                 dtype='f'           # use float32 first
                 ).astype('int8')    # then convert to int8
```

`ss.random` only supports float types of which `float32` is the smallest, whereas `int8` is the smallest integer type available.

See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.random.html for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.random.randint(0,2,1000)
```

will generate 1000 random variables between 0 and 1 inclusive. Then, it's up to you what kind of container you want to use for the matrix

```
my_v = np.random.randint(0,5,1000)
my_v[my_v>1]=1
```

Comment: That's a very memory-inefficient way to initialize a sparse matrix if the dimensions are large

Comment: Can I choose density this way?

Comment: it has a Uniform distribution. Do you have a specific density function in mind?

Comment: Well I want a density of 20% non-zero values. Is this possible?

Although the other answer does what I want, I may still need to use this method later.

Comment: Then this is a math trick :) ... make a np.random.randint(0,5,1000) and then replace everything >0 with ones ;)

Comment: Woops, meant 80% but I understand the method. Thanks for your help :)